# C++ program exiting with some return value without running some lines?

Tags: c++

Okay so I'm trying to make a program that adds and displays student records but the thing is my program runs only half way and then exits with some return value. Can someone please guide me through what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Students
{
 private:
     string id;
     string name;
     float cgpa;
 public:
    Students()
    {
        id=" ";
        name=" ";
        cgpa=0.0;
    }
    void Add_Student()
    {
        cout<<"Enter Student Name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,name);  //The program runs fine till here and then exits without displaying anything else.
        cout<<"Enter Student ID: ";
        cin>>id;
        cout<<"Enter CGPA: ";
        cin>>cgpa;
    }
    void Display_Students()
    {
        cout<<"Student Name: "<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"Student ID: "<<id<<endl;
        cout<<"Student CGPA: "<<cgpa<<endl<<endl;
    }
};
main()
{
 int n=0;
 Students S[n];
 again:
 char choice=' ';
 cout<<"Press 1 To Add Student, 2 To Display Students List, Anything Else To Exit:  ";
 cin>>choice;
 if(choice=='1')
 {
     cin.ignore();
     S[n].Add_Student();
     ++n;
     goto again;
 }
 else if(choice=='2')
 {
     for(int i; i<n; ++i)
     {
         S[i].Display_Students();
         goto again;
     }
 }
 else
 {
     exit(0);
 }
}
```

Look closely at void Add_Student() the program works fine till getting the name and after that it does not run any cout statement or anything it just exits with some return value.

Comment: Program exits with *what* error value? What other output do you get (that was not intended by you)? What input do you provide? Please provide [mcve]

Comment: In `S[n].Add_Student();` it looks like you expect arrays to grow when you try to access them out of bounds. That is not how they work. Accessing an array element beyond it's end is Undefined Behavior and anything can happen. Since your array is defined to have 0 elements, there is nothing you can do with it. Use `std::vector` instead and `emplace_back` to insert new elements.

Comment: In c++ you may not omit the return type of `int` functions. You need to write `int main`.

Comment: Within your `main` function you allocate your Students array with size 0. Accessing element on index 0 wil give a core dump

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Process exited after 7.451 seconds with return value 3221225477

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I haven't learned about vectors yet I need to complete this task assigned by my teacher using arrays only

Comment: @RobertKock what should I do then? I want to set the values from index 0 and so on

Comment: @Umair The easiest solution is to define `S` to be a sufficiently large array and make sure the user doesn't add more elements than that. For example `Students s[10];` and don't allow the user to add more than 10 students. But that is a very weak solution. `std::vector` is a standard feature. It's the tool that should be used here.

Comment: Please don't use `goto` statements C++. Use a loop instead

Comment: @RobertKock thank you! your first comment made me look at my code again and it solved the problem I was creating new objects by S[n]

Comment: I'm troubled.  I strongly believe that teachers shouldn't be teaching `goto`.  They are far too easy to abuse and cause all manner of hard to detect bugs.  Anything that can be done with `if` and `goto` can be done better with `for` and `while` (and maybe `do{}while`).  You should not be using `goto`.  You should not have been *taught* `goto`.  So if you learned it on your own, that's fine, just realize that there is a good reason you are being taught what you are being taught *in that order*.  If not... well... that's bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a first glance, in your main function the vector of students Students S[n] has size 0 because n is 0. You try to access an element from vector S which is beyond the memory limits of S (S having size 0), and this is undefined behaviour. If you don't know how many students you will have, you can use std::vector and call push_back whenever you add a new student. Read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for more info about the std::vector container.

Answer (score 0):

Delete **cin.ignore()** from your code